# PHPExcel error when reading calculated value

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I have a cell in an excel sheet that i am trying to read.
When I use the function getCalculatedValue it's throwing following error:

```
Financials!LU83 -> Financials!LU81 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured
```

I wrote following function to read from a cell

```
private function getCellValue($data)
{

        //example of data variable
        //$data = [0, 'G79'];

        $excel = $this->excel;
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex($data[0]);
        \PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($excel)->flushInstance();
        \PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($excel)->clearCalculationCache();
        return $excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($data[1])->getCalculatedValue();

    }
```

that cell that I am trying to read has following value

> =LU83+LT84

where LU83 has following value

> =LU73-SUM(LU76:LU81)

LU81 has value

> =VLOOKUP(LU8,'Wiser Return'!$O:$S,5,0)

I have no idea why I am getting this error. I wish there was a way to debug? Is there a way?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPEXCEL getCalculatedValue or getFormattedValue returns fatal error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966752/phpexcel-getcalculatedvalue-or-getformattedvalue-returns-fatal-error)

Comment: So what does cell LU81 contain? That's the cell that it's complaining about

Comment: =VLOOKUP(LU8,'Wiser Return'!$O:$S,5,0)

Comment: I will look at that post and update my code, I will update this thread as soon as I do

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that PHPExcel's calculation engine does not fully support row or column ranges.

```
=VLOOKUP(LU8,'Wiser Return'!$O:$S,5,0)
```

contains the column range `$O:$S`

If this can be converted to a cell range instead, e.g

```
=VLOOKUP(LU8,'Wiser Return'!$O1:$S1024,5,0)
```

then it should handle the formula correctly

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment now, but I found some link that might help you.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966752/phpexcel-getcalculatedvalue-or-getformattedvalue-returns-fatal-error) the accepted answer states, that you can get further information about the error with this [gist](https://gist.github.com/MarkBaker/5908357).

(I suggest deleting your question if this helped you.)

Comment: ok, I will read that post and try it in my code and delete this topic if it solved it thank you